# Ubuntu 16.04 WSL libGL error

Tags: 16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Similar posts have been made about this, but all involve nvidia which I do not have. I am getting the following errors printed to my terminal every time I launch something with GUI using X-ming or similar with my WSL:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

These errors do not prevent me from using the programs/GUIs, but they are super annoying. I also get other errors printed to my terminal often that seemingly have no purpose or solutions. I cannot find a fix that does not relate to having an Nvidia graphics card. I have Intel HD Graphics 530 installed on this PC. Again, I'm using the windows linux subsystem.

Comment: Try setting `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` in the remote environment as described here: [Trouble with Xming?](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php)

Comment: I tried that and nothing has changed. I also tried `glxinfo | grep OpenG` as suggested in the same link ([link](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/trouble.php)) but I don't understand this output. It doesn't seem to mention a graphic card:`OpenGL vendor string: Microsoft Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GDI Generic
OpenGL version string: 1.1.0
OpenGL extensions:`

Comment: Try with latest Ubuntu versions e.g. 18.x or 19.x.